# Windows is hibernated, refuses to mount

Tags: startup, hibernate, windows-10

Having done all the steps to get Ubuntu in USB.
Starting from USB, I have Ubuntu running properly BUT I cannot open Windows files because

> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
>   Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
>   The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: You need to turn off Windows hibernation feature and disable secureboot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1- Reboot your Ubuntu and open windows, then turn off fast boot.
[Turn off windows 10 fast boot](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html).

2- Reboot your Ubuntu and open windows, then restart your windows and open Ubuntu. You will find that problem is solved because restarting close all partitions.

Note : If you choose option 2 you will need to do it every time you want to use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Disable hibernation and Fast startup. Boot the Windows operating system.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute : `powercfg /h off`.

Open Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings and uncheck Fast startup.
In case it is not visible, enable show hidden settings.

Shutdown the machine completely, do NOT reboot.
Now you are able to access the Windows partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not seem to have the option mentioned in other answers (at least I could not find it). Simply **Hold the shift key when you tell Windows to shut down.**  works like a charm!

Comment: Done but the problem continues: Ubuntu requires 10 to 15 minutes to start up

Comment: You have problems then for sure.  How long does a live usb take?  If a minute or two, then wipe and reinstall again.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about the usb. Ubuntu is working properly but the startup is intolerable. I mean: ubuntu is installed now in my PC; in the grub I click ubuntu and I get immediately a violet page for 10secs; then a dark gray page for 3secs; then a black page with a small drums sound; then wait for 5' at least; then press any key and appears the password request. It seems to me that, starting the black page, ubuntu begins to sleep for 5', then automatically wakes up.

Comment: You installed from a live USB.  Try to load that.  If you used a dvd.  The boot with that. see how long it takes.  If you have a slow and old system.  Try Lubuntu.  That is what I run.

Comment: Hmmmm! Now I remember that, when I installed Ubuntu from a live USB, Windows was not "full shutdown". I'm going to repeat the installation and I'll inform you about that. Tks.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 but the result is the same: wait 5' to complete the start up. I think that it is a big bug.

Comment: what are the specs on your computer?  or how many years old is it?  Try lubuntu

Comment: My computer is an HP Pavilion 20, one year old. I installed also Lubuntu and Kbuntu but the results are the same.

Comment: Are you sure you are fully closing down windows?  The shift key works..hold down the shift key the entire time while clicking the start, power options and shutdown.   Try the other things listed to disable fast boot.  Are the disks on the windows patition on available?   This will answer many questions about shutdown.  You can also do verbose booting of ubuntu Google it.  There is also a tool to give a boot report.  I forget the name..  good luck

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions:
1. Ubuntu cannot open Windows files: Fully shut down Windows10 holding down the Shift key and clicking Shut-down option.
2. Ubuntu Start-up too long (5' to 10'): Before closing Ubuntu (for next time you will open it) open Terminal and type the command:

```
dmesg > /tmp/dmesg.txt; gedit /tmp/dmesg.txt
```

This works only once so, my suggestion, is to do it every time that you close Ubuntu.